# Recursive Mogrify Script

Tags: linux, mogrify

Another question from a newbie linux scripter. I'm trying to batch mogrify all the files in a folder using this command

```
find -name "*.jpg" -exec mogrify -resize 320 -quality 75 {} \;
```

The command runs but nothing seems to happen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
find -name "*.jpg" -print
```

to see what files match; this may help diagnose if the problem is with mogrify or with find.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry all but this was just user error. I was not in the correct folder when testing. The command actually does work.

Comment: In that case, you should mark Joel's answer as correct, since that was the debugging that would identify your error.